# escaped backslash coming out as "\\" in string

Tags: javascript, string, escaping

So while working on one of my first Node.js projects utilizing the file system I came across some behavior that stumped me. I had read that in JS when you need to put backslashes in a string you have to add an extra backslash to escape it. Even the text formatting on here on Stack Overflow is doing it correctly.

Example:

```
let str = "dir1\\file.txt" /* used two '\\' */
```

This made perfect sense to me. However when I print these strings to the console in Node.js they still appear to have that extra backslash still present. I did however test this on the browser console and it seems to be working fine. Why does this not work for Node.js? Does Node.js for some reason just not follow this JavaScript convention?

The personal project I've been working on has come to a complete stop for the past few days as a result of this confusion. So any clarity on this this would greatly help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`console.log` functions give you debugging information. Different implementations of `console.log` are different. There is no standard which describes how they should represent a string.

Often they provide representations of strings that include escape characters in the visible output.

If you want to see the processed value of the string in Node, then write to [STDOUT](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_stdout).

```
process.stdout.write("Your \\ string");
```

Answer (score 2):

The string contains only one backslash regardless.

When you output a string in the Node.js console directly, it shows the string's contents. For example,

```
console.log("testing\\123");
```

outputs

```
testing\123
```

But when you output something like an object, Node.js shows a representation of that object, and in that representation, it shows the strings in *string literal* format. For example,

```
console.log({example: "testing\\123"});
```

outputs

```
{ example: 'testing\\123' }
```

Note the `'` around the string literal, and the fact the backslash is escaped.

There's only one backslash there, it's just that it's showing you the string in *string literal* notation.

Browser consoles vary in how they show those two examples. For instance, Chrome's console shows them like this (at present, v72):

[image]

Chrome's console output for the second example is (to my mind) rather more confusing than Node.js's output, because although the string is shown in quotes, it's **not** a string literal. It's just the string contents. (I would *much* prefer it showed a string literal, or failing that, didn't show the string in quotes. What it does is a distant third choice in my view.)

This is purely a difference in how the consoles show the string. The string is the same in both cases: It has **one** backslash in it.